# How can I get an expected value of a random variable from its sum to another variable?

Tags: probability

Apologies for not knowing how best to word this problem; I'm not experienced in probability and I don't know where to start looking for this question (or even how to tag this).

I have some continuous random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, and a constant $c$, which are related as
$Z = cX+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I know the probability distributions of $X$ and $Y$, so it's straightforward to get the CDF of $Z$ as a function of $c$. I also know what I want $z$ and $\text{Prob}(Z>z)$ to be, so it's easy to then solve for $c$. But now I need a corresponding value for $X$, and I'm not sure what the options are or how to calculate them. What other information do I need to get a useful value for $X$? I thought I could just use the expected value, but that doesn't take into account the values of $z$, $\text{Prob}(Z>z)$, and $c$.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is hard to follow.  $X$ is a random variable...it hasn't got a fixed "value".  What is it you are trying to do here?

Comment: I suggest:  clearly state what information is known and what it is you would like to determine.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to make an edit but I again am not sure how to word things . Does the distribution of X change when I know what Z and Prob(Z) are? Can I simply use the expectation value of that new distribution?

Comment: Again, I don't understand what information is given.  For example, I thought that $X,Y$ were given.